# How to change the display Language of text in Browser from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, project

How can i change the language of the text in browser when i launched the project from eclipse ?
By default it will display in the english language.

```
Tools --> options --> Content --> choose Language ---> Set language
```

This path works fine to change the language of the browser but not works when i launch any project from eclipse ?

Comment: From your question I'm guessing you are developing a web project. This really depends on the technology/framework you use. In most cases you can set the default locale somewhere in a configuration file. You could also change the language/locale of your browser which is usually used to determine locale to load for your website.

Comment: I'm just realizing you set the language in your browser and not in Eclipse. I'm guessing Firefox? Which framework do you use for web development?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel : using GWT. and yes, i changed it for browser as well my Main.gwt.xml file but even after that not able to change the language. i.e. <extend-property name="locale" values="it" />

Comment: Hmm, can't help you with GWT, sorry. Been a few years since I last used it ;-)